# How to close tab automatically if URL has specific word?

Tags: urls

help me today.

Is it possible to close the tab automatically after loading/few seconds after checking if URL address has specific words?

e.g; `http://mysite.com/post.php?deleted=1`

Here `?deleted=1` is the word I'd like to check. I'm on wordpress. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need Javascript to do this. You can use [`window.close()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.close?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.close).

So adding this script to your page should do the job:

```
function check_if_should_close(url) {
    if ( PUT YOUR CONDITION HERE )  // i.e. url.match(/\?deleted=1/)
        return true;
    return false;
}

if ( check_if_should_close(document.location.href) ) {
    window.close();
}
```

Comment: Just tried, I didn't work. I got error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'match' of undefined "

Comment: Sorry, simple mistake. Updated my answer it should be ok now.

Comment: `document.URL.match` also works :) Thanks. Both methods are working.

Comment: Yes, but it's better to use location.href (location could cause some problems in IE, AFAIR).